# Why can't i create a RESTful web service in ejb module?

Tags: java, web-services

I am using Netbeans 6.8. I can see an option to create a web service in my independent ejb module but i can't seem to find an option to create a RESTful based web service in my ejb module. Is there any kind of restriction in ejb module that i can only create SOAP based web service and not RESTful? or is it the bug of Netbeans 6.8?

Comment: How did you solve your problem can you please explain? Did you shifted to soap or did on restfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chapter 2.6 of the EJB3 specs:

> To support web service
>   interoperability, the EJB speciﬁcation
>   requires compliant implementations to 
>   support XML-based web service
>   invocations using WSDL and SOAP or
>   plain XML over HTTP incon-  formance
>   with the requirements of the
>   JAX-WS[32], JAX-RPC[25], Web Services
>   for JavaEE[31],  and Web Services
>   Metadata for the Java Platform [30]
>   speciﬁcations.

In other words: EJB3 can be exposed only as SOAP web service.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Then finally i should drop the idea of using RESTful web services in my project.

Comment: No, I disagree.  Use REST if it's appropriate.  You just shouldn't expect to do with EJB3 support.  That doesn't mean it can't or shouldn't be done.

Comment: I have same doubt. I am trying to make ejb module as restfull web service. But I did not get any resources. @duffymo. From your comment it made me confuse. I do not know whether my language problem or not. But you are disagree with the answer. May I make like question said? I do not want to create web module and call to ejb. want to only ejb module to deploy on the server and run as webservice. Any information or link will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

REST is just HTTP, usually implemented with servlets, so it would naturally be added to a WAR file that may or may not be packaged into an EAR with EJBs.

I don't believe that EJBs know or care about SOAP or REST.  EJBs use RMI as their communication protocol of choice.

Comment: Hi duffymo, web services are also in my opinion type of ejbs in java? since we can mark the webservice to be @Stateless similar to ejbs. Also my ejb module, btw i am talking about independent ejb module (.jar) not EAR contains web services (SOAP based) and it works just fine. All web services are inside .jar(my independent ejb module) and not .war

Comment: You can annotate the EJB in a way so that the app. server will exposed it as web service, without adding anything more to your EJB project.

Comment: Yeah ewernli, i said the same thing in my comment

Answer (score 2):

I found an article about [EJB 3.1 and JSR-311 REST](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_13) but I've to admit that I never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper class to the EJB which you are going to mark it as restful webservice with Jax-rs annotations with support of CXF rest api or Jersey api.